# Django rest framework AttributeError: can't find field on Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

**Background context**

---

I'm using django rest framework and django-rest-auth to build an API. My authentication scheme doesn't use the default authentication of just the email/username and password and requires other data present on the `Profile` model.

For this reason, I'm using a custom registration serializer and overriding the `REGISTER_SERIALIZER` class in the settings.

This is the serializer as follows:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()

    class Meta(object):
        model = Profile
        fields = ('phone_number', 'birth_date', 'anniversary', 'user_type',)



class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=get_username_max_length(),
        min_length=allauth_settings.USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH,
        required=allauth_settings.USERNAME_REQUIRED
    )
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=allauth_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
    serializers.EmailField(required=allauth_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    profile = UserProfileSerializer()


..............
Validation methods
..............

def custom_signup(self, request, user):
    pass

def get_cleaned_data(self):
    return {
        'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
        'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
        'email': self.validated_data.get('email', '')
    }

def save(self, request):
    adapter = get_adapter()
    user = adapter.new_user(request)
    self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
    adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
    self.custom_signup(request, user)
    setup_user_email(request, user, [])

    profile_data = self.validated_data.pop('profile', {})
    user_repo.create_object(user=user, **profile_data)

    return user
```

---

**The problem**

The serializer and the corresponding endpoint works in that it is creating the user and the associated profile, but in the serializing step when returning the response, I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `profile` on serializer `UserRegisterSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `OrderedDict` instance.
Original exception text was: 'profile'."
```

As you can see, the field exists on the serializer. I tried adding the field to the `Meta` classe's field property but it didn't work.

I've narrowed it down to the function `to_representation` in `rest_framework/serializers.py` at line number `488`. The error occurs when the serializer tries call `get_attribute` on on the nested serializer.

Thanks!

**Edit** : [This is the view in library which uses this serializer](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/registration/views.py#L32)

**Edit-1** : [Stack trace of the error](https://pastebin.com/8VYENgsB)

Comment: Could you show the view?

Comment: The view is the default view which `django-rest-framework` uses. I can link to it

Comment: Could you also post the full stack trace?

Comment: @FazilZaid sure thing

Comment: have you added 'REGISTER_SERIALIZER' field in your settings file, as you're using custom one?

Comment: Yup, if I didn't then the save method on this serializer wouldn't have been called, not creating the profile in the first place.